# A real time moving point does not change the position on the map in MapBox under Blazor

Tags: mapbox, real-time, blazor

I am using MapBox under Blazor. There is a point with JSON coordinates changing in realtime. In Index razor page on mouse click I call the javascript function:

```
refreshJSON: function (str) { 
  window.jsontest = JSON.parse(str);
  window.map.getSource('drone').setData(window.jsontest);
}
```

where jsontest contains new coordinates, but the point does not change position on the screen. 
How can I fix the problem?
In Index.razor code:

```
public void refreshMapJson()
{
    refreshCoords();
    JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("mapBoxFunctions.refreshJSON",currJson);
    InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }
     );
}
```

Comment: Try this: remove the call to InvokeAsync from your code, and place what is left in the OnAfterRenderAsync method

Comment: This works. The point changes position, but the entire map is redrawn (~3 sec), not just the point. This does not suit

Answer (score 1):

Await your method :

```
public async Tassk refreshMapJson()
{
    refreshCoords();
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("mapBoxFunctions.refreshJSON",currJson);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

If you don't want to use awaitable method then call `StateHasChanged` when `JSRuntime.InvokeAsync`return;

```
public void refreshMapJson()
{
    refreshCoords();
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("mapBoxFunctions.refreshJSON",currJson)
       .ContinueWith(t => StateHasChanged());
}
```

Comment: In the first case  the point changes position, but the entire map is redrawn  (~3 sec), not just the point. This is not suit. I used next code:                                                          
private async Task callJson()
    {
        Time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
        refreshCoords();
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("refreshJSON",currJson)
               .ConfigureAwait(false);
          await   InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
    }

Comment: In the second case - ValueTask does not contain a definition  for "ContinueWith" .         
If you use the code "JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("refreshJSON",currJson).AsTask().ContinueWith(t => StateHasChanged());" then I get an error- "The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.'"

Comment: oh ya I forgot that

Answer (score 1):

One of the MapBox developers said what is wrong.

> you're passing the source definition instead of the data to setData, which rightfully thinks this isn't valid GeoJSON. This works:

```
map.getSource('drone').setData(window.jsonleft.data);
```